# Meaning of specific MATLAB instruction num2str

Tags: string, matlab, type-conversion, string-concatenation

I have been sent some complete MATLAB script. It appears that author of this code has made a specific instruction using `num2str` and `set_param` .
What is the purpose of the following line:

```
['[' num2str(operating_point) ']']
```

I am interested specially of an intention of using `'['` as syntax.

```
set_param(system_block_name, operating_point_name,...
        ['[' num2str(operating_point) ']']
```

Comment: Have you looked at the help https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html and tried using it in MATLAB?

Comment: Did you try creating a numeric variable `operating_point` and and executing that first line of code?

Comment: Yes, yes. I do understand what does  `num2str` . I was wondering why the author of that code used braces in apostrophe `'['`  and  `']'` , because I think it's unnecessary.

Comment: Then you didn't actually try the command, or you would see what the single-quotes do. I wasn't trying to get you to run `num2str`, I was trying to get you to execute the part you had the actual question about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB rectangular braces `[]` create vector/matrix. 
By default, horizontal vector of strings concatenated into 1 string:

```
['str1','str2'] % produces str1str2
```

So

```
['[',']'] % will print []
```

`num2str()` converts number into string:

```
a=10;
my_str = ['[',num2str(a),']'] % will assign my_str = '[10]'
```

`set_param()` is some function that gets 3 parameters, where 3rd one is your string